# How to detect if metabox content was updated by the user

Tags: metabox

I am handling metaboxes and their updating process the standard way:

```
// Attached to the save_post hook
function the_save_stuff_handler($post_id, $post){

    // Early return
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE){
        return $post_id;
    }
    
    // Again
    if(!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)){
        return $post_id;
    }

    ...

    // HANDLE META WHATEVERNAME1
    // here --> check_things_are_okay (validation, sanitize, etc)
    update_post_meta(...);

    // HANDLE META WHATEVERNAME2
    // here --> check_things_are_okay (validation, sanitize, etc)
    update_post_meta(...);

}
```

I want to know if there is something I can do to only run the parts for each block "HANDLE META WHATEVERNAME1", "HANDLE META WHATEVERNAME2" ... if the metabox was actually modified.

The purpose of this is to save database queries and just not perform the update if there isn't anything else to update. I find it is not very smooth to just re-update the meta values over and over again with the same value. Or maybe we want to send an email or perform whatever other action if changes are detected.

The solution I have been playing with is quite simple:

Use `get_post_meta()` and check if the value matches the submitted value or not.

But I wonder if there is some other way to do it without requiring a call to the database.

This may be a stupid question because there actually is a trivial solution, which I mentioned. But sometimes I am blind to alternative trivial solutions and in the case of WordPress there are often hidden gems that are very helpful.

And that is why I am posting this.

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: Your attempt to be efficient is noble but you are consuming more process cycles attempting to save some.  I would suggest simply saving the value each time as originally designed, whether the value has been modified or not.

Comment: @jdm2112 Seems a pretty logic reasoning. Thank you, will do that.